# HTTP status codes - API Rest

Tags: php, http, response, requests, headers

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar una **API Rest** y quisiera mostrar el código del servidor correspondiente, en función de las peticiones que se realicen.

Lo estoy pensando de la siguiente manera:

Copié un `array` de la página de PHP y pensaba mostrarlos con un `foreach` con un `http_response_code.` Vi algo de los *headers* y `php_sapi_name` pero no le cacé aún la idea.

No sé si tendrán relación con lo que quiero hacer. En si el punto es mostrar de manera correcta el status y su correspondiente mensaje. ¿Cómo podría ser? Espero haber sido claro. De antemano, gracias.

```
<?php

foreach ($http_status_codes as $code){
    http_response_code($code);
}

$http_status_codes = array( 100 => "Continue",
                            101 => "Switching Protocols",
                            102 => "Processing",
                            200 => "OK",
                            201 => "Created",
                            202 => "Accepted",
                            203 => "Non-Authoritative Information",
                            204 => "No Content",
                            205 => "Reset Content",
                            206 => "Partial Content",
                            207 => "Multi-Status",
                            300 => "Multiple Choices",
                            301 => "Moved Permanently",
                            302 => "Found",
                            303 => "See Other",
                            304 => "Not Modified",
                            305 => "Use Proxy",
                            306 => "(Unused)",
                            307 => "Temporary Redirect",
                            308 => "Permanent Redirect",
                            400 => "Bad Request",
                            401 => "Unauthorized",
                            402 => "Payment Required",
                            403 => "Forbidden",
                            404 => "Not Found",
                            405 => "Method Not Allowed",
                            406 => "Not Acceptable",
                            407 => "Proxy Authentication Required",
                            408 => "Request Timeout",
                            409 => "Conflict",
                            410 => "Gone",
                            411 => "Length Required",
                            412 => "Precondition Failed",
                            413 => "Request Entity Too Large",
                            414 => "Request-URI Too Long",
                            415 => "Unsupported Media Type",
                            416 => "Requested Range Not Satisfiable",
                            417 => "Expectation Failed",
                            418 => "I'm a teapot",
                            419 => "Authentication Timeout",
                            420 => "Enhance Your Calm",
                            422 => "Unprocessable Entity",
                            423 => "Locked",
                            424 => "Failed Dependency",
                            425 => "Unordered Collection",
                            426 => "Upgrade Required",
                            428 => "Precondition Required",
                            429 => "Too Many Requests",
                            431 => "Request Header Fields Too Large",
                            444 => "No Response",
                            449 => "Retry With",
                            450 => "Blocked by Windows Parental Controls",
                            451 => "Unavailable For Legal Reasons",
                            494 => "Request Header Too Large",
                            495 => "Cert Error",
                            496 => "No Cert",
                            497 => "HTTP to HTTPS",
                            499 => "Client Closed Request",
                            500 => "Internal Server Error",
                            501 => "Not Implemented",
                            502 => "Bad Gateway",
                            503 => "Service Unavailable",
                            504 => "Gateway Timeout",
                            505 => "HTTP Version Not Supported",
                            506 => "Variant Also Negotiates",
                            507 => "Insufficient Storage",
                            508 => "Loop Detected",
                            509 => "Bandwidth Limit Exceeded",
                            510 => "Not Extended",
                            511 => "Network Authentication Required",
                            598 => "Network read timeout error",
                            599 => "Network connect timeout error");
```

Encontré lo siguiente y quería saber si hay manera de juntarlo con lo descrito anteriormente:

```
$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if (substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) == 'cgi')
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
else
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: No entendí bien. ¿Quieres mostrar un mensaje personalizado por cada código de error?

Comment: @A.Cedano Exactamente

Comment: @A.Cedano, ahora voy a realizar un par de pruebas y le comentó que ha sucedido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar mensajes personalizados por cada código de error, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear tu propio array `$http_status_codes` como ya haces, asociando cada código de error a un mensaje concreto.
2. Obtener mediante [`http_response_code`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.http-response-code.php) el código de error ocurrido.
3. Buscar en el array el índice que corresponde a ese código de error.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mCode=http_response_code();
#Aquí pones tus mensajes personalizados
$http_status_codes = array( 100 => "Continue",
                            101 => "Switching Protocols",
                            102 => "Processing",
                            200 => "OK",
                            201 => "Created",
                            202 => "Accepted",
                            203 => "Non-Authoritative Information",
                            204 => "No Content",
                            205 => "Reset Content",
                            206 => "Partial Content",
                            207 => "Multi-Status",
                            300 => "Multiple Choices",
                            301 => "Moved Permanently",
                            302 => "Found",
                            303 => "See Other",
                            304 => "Not Modified",
                            305 => "Use Proxy",
                            306 => "(Unused)",
                            307 => "Temporary Redirect",
                            308 => "Permanent Redirect",
                            400 => "Bad Request",
                            401 => "Unauthorized",
                            402 => "Payment Required",
                            403 => "Forbidden",
                            404 => "Not Found",
                            405 => "Method Not Allowed",
                            406 => "Not Acceptable",
                            407 => "Proxy Authentication Required",
                            408 => "Request Timeout",
                            409 => "Conflict",
                            410 => "Gone",
                            411 => "Length Required",
                            412 => "Precondition Failed",
                            413 => "Request Entity Too Large",
                            414 => "Request-URI Too Long",
                            415 => "Unsupported Media Type",
                            416 => "Requested Range Not Satisfiable",
                            417 => "Expectation Failed",
                            418 => "I'm a teapot",
                            419 => "Authentication Timeout",
                            420 => "Enhance Your Calm",
                            422 => "Unprocessable Entity",
                            423 => "Locked",
                            424 => "Failed Dependency",
                            425 => "Unordered Collection",
                            426 => "Upgrade Required",
                            428 => "Precondition Required",
                            429 => "Too Many Requests",
                            431 => "Request Header Fields Too Large",
                            444 => "No Response",
                            449 => "Retry With",
                            450 => "Blocked by Windows Parental Controls",
                            451 => "Unavailable For Legal Reasons",
                            494 => "Request Header Too Large",
                            495 => "Cert Error",
                            496 => "No Cert",
                            497 => "HTTP to HTTPS",
                            499 => "Client Closed Request",
                            500 => "Internal Server Error",
                            501 => "Not Implemented",
                            502 => "Bad Gateway",
                            503 => "Service Unavailable",
                            504 => "Gateway Timeout",
                            505 => "HTTP Version Not Supported",
                            506 => "Variant Also Negotiates",
                            507 => "Insufficient Storage",
                            508 => "Loop Detected",
                            509 => "Bandwidth Limit Exceeded",
                            510 => "Not Extended",
                            511 => "Network Authentication Required",
                            598 => "Network read timeout error",
                            599 => "Network connect timeout error");

#Controlamos para asignar un mensaje por defecto si el código no existe
$mError=( array_key_exists($mCode, $http_status_codes) ) ? "Error $mCode: ".$http_status_codes[$mCode] : "El código de error no existe en el array";
echo $mError;
```